# copying columns from different files into a single file using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have about more than 500 files having two columns "Gene short name" and "FPKM" values. The number of rows is same and the "Gene short name" column is common in all the files. I want to create a matrix by keeping first column as gene short name (can be taken from any of the files) and rest other columns having the FPKM.

I have used this command which works well, but then, how can I use it for 500 files?

```
 paste -d' ' <(awk -F'\t' '{print $1}' 69_genes.fpkm.txt) \
            <(awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' 69_genes.fpkm.txt) \
            <(awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' 72_genes.fpkm.txt) \
            <(awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' 75_genes.fpkm.txt) \
            <(awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' 78_genes.fpkm.txt) > col.txt
```

sample data (files are tab separated):

```
head 69_genes.fpkm.txt 
gene_short_name FPKM
        DDX11L1 0.196141
        MIR1302-2HG 0.532631
        MIR1302-2   0
        WASH7P  4.51437
```

Expected outcome

```
gene_short_name FPKM FPKM FPKM FPKM
DDX11L1 0.196141 0.206591 0.0201256 0.363618
MIR1302-2HG 0.532631 0.0930007 0.0775838 0
MIR1302-2 0 0 0 0
WASH7P 4.51437 3.31073 3.23326 1.05673
MIR6859-1 0 0 0 0
FAM138A 0.505155 0.121703 0.105235 0
OR4G4P 0.0536387 0 0 0
OR4G11P 0 0 0 0
OR4F5 0.0390888 0.0586067 0 0
```

Also, I want to change the name "FPKM" to "filename_FPKM".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input

```
$ cat a.txt
a       1
b       2
c       3
$ cat b.txt
a       I
b       II
c       III
$ cat c.txt
a       one
b       two
c       three
```

you can loop:

```
cut -f1 a.txt > result.txt
for f in a.txt b.txt c.txt
do
  cut -f2 "$f" | paste result.txt - > tmp.txt
  mv {tmp,result}.txt
done
```

```
$ cat result.txt
a       1       I       one
b       2       II      two
c       3       III     three
```

Comment: As an alternative to a temporary file there is the `sponge` command from `moreutils`: `cut -f2 "$f" | paste result.txt - | sponge result.txt`

Comment: To put the file names into the header, use `cut -f2 "$f" | sed "1s/.*/$f/" | paste ...`.

Comment: thanks @Micha, I used your approach and gave the path to the directory having all the input files:


`cut -f1 file.fpkm.txt > result.txt  \
for f in /path/to/input_files/*.fpkm.txt  \
do  \
  cut -f2 "$f" | sed "1s/.*/$f/" | paste result.txt - > tmp.txt  \
  mv tmp.txt result.txt  \
done ` \

The sed command from @Socowi doesn't work though. I get this error:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: @MadhulikaVerma it does not work since you used whole paths. If you only pass the actual file name it should work unless you have special symbols like `&` or `\ ` in the file name. Try `sed "1s/.*/$(basename "$f")/"`.

Comment: @Socowi It does work now, but the first column header is a blank space now. Although I can do it with sed seperately.

Answer (score 0):

In awk, using @Micha's data for clarity:

```
$ awk '  
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }    # set the field separators
FNR==1 {
    $2=FILENAME "_" $2   # on first record of each file rename $2
}
NR==FNR {                # process the first file
    a[FNR]=$0            # hash whole record to a
    next
}
{                        # process other files
    a[FNR]=a[FNR] OFS $2 # add $2 to the end of the record
}
END {                    # in the end
    for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)  # print all records
        print a[i]
}' a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Output:

```
a       a.txt_1 b.txt_I c.txt_one
b       2       II      two
c       3       III     three
```